# "noise" module: how to reseed?

Tags: python, perlin-noise

The perlin noise lib at [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/noise/) seems to be the most-used Perlin noise module for Python. But there is one problem with it--there is no way to call the randomize() function that exists in `perlin.py` in the git repository.

Assuming the module is imported using

```
import noise
```

and used by

```
snoise(x, y)
```

, the randomize() function is not accessible. **Is there a way to seed the noise functions that I haven't discovered?** If I wanted to use `snoise()` to generate different values for the same coordinates, I would have to restart the entire program.